# Питон, ошибка в цикле for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется цикл перебора значений от 1 до N-го. В нем задаются две новые переменные с первоначальным значением 0. Следует узнать, при каком числе эти две переменные будут иметь определенные значения (*допустим 1 и 2*).

Код:

```py
for x in range(1, 999):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    while x > 0:
        a += 1
        b = b + x % 10
        x = x // 10
        if a == 3 and b == 7:
            print(x)
        else:
            pass
```

При компиляции выдает 0, хотя быть такого не должно. Запускаю все на версии 3.10.

Прошу объяснить, в чем моя ошибка и почему компилятор не выдает нужных значений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выдает всегда 0 из-за того, что внутри цикла переменная x изменяется. Вам нужно копировать в начале x и уже потом выводить эту нетронутую переменную. Код:

```py
for x in range(1, 999):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    orig_x = x
    while x > 0:
        a += 1
        b = b + x % 10
        x = x // 10
        if a == 3 and b == 7:
            print(orig_x)
        else:
            pass
```